# Docker DinD fails to build images after upgrading

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We are using Docker 18.9.8-dind. [DinD — Docker-in-Docker — is running Docker in a separate container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker). This way, we send requests to this container to build our images, instead of executing Docker in the machine that wants the built image.

We needed to upgrade from 18.9.8-dind to 20.10.14-dind. Since we use Kubernetes, we just updated the image version in some YAML files:

```
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: builder
-        image: docker:18.09.8-dind
+        image: docker:20.10.14-dind
         args: ["--storage-driver", "overlay2", "--mtu", "1460"]
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         resources:
```

Alas, things stopped working after that. Builds failed, and we could find these error messages in the code reaching for our Docker builder:

```
{"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"123.456.789.10","port":2375}
Something went wrong and the entire build was interrupted due to an incorrect configuration file or build step,
check your source code.
```

What can be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We checked the logs in the Docker pod, and found this message at the end:

```
API listen on [::]:2376
```

Well, our message in the question states we tried to connect to port 2375, which used to work. Why has the port changed?

[Docker enables TLS as default](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/#TLS) from version 19.03 onwards. [When Docker uses TLS, it listens on port 2376](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2020/02/25/docker-image/).

We had three alternatives here:

- change the port to 2375 (which sounds like a bad idea: we would use the default plain port for TLS communication, a very confusing setup);
- Connect to the new port; or
- disable TLS.

In general, connecting to the new port is probably the best solution.

(Nonetheless, we choose to disable TLS because we were moving away from DinD anyway, and the app that connected to it was not in our control. It only required an environment variable in yet another YAML file:

```
       - name: builder
         image: docker:20.10.14-dind
         args: ["--storage-driver", "overlay2", "--mtu", "1460"]
+        env:
+        - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
+          value: ""
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         resources:
           requests:
```

In most scenarios, though, it is probably better to have TLS enabled and change the port in the client.)

*(Sharing in the spirit of [Can I answer my own questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) because it took us some time to piece the parts together. Maybe by sharing this information together with the error message, things can be easier for other affected people to find.)*

Comment: [Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/#tls)